# How can I make a thread respond to a joinable queue message to update my wx Phoenix UI?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, wxpython

I have an app with a long running background (daemon) process and a wx based UI. The background process puts messages in a multiprocessing.JoinableQueue() which the UI should read from to get status updates on the daemon process while it is running. The issue I am having is while the AwaitStatusReportThreadClass instance passes the message to the UI, it causes the UI to stop responding. If you run the code below and then try to resize the window the app shows as not responding.

I'm running this on Windows 7 using Python27 32bit, wxPython 4.0.0a3 (Phoenix)

My app is structured with various python files, but I was able to reproduce the error with the below code. It's pretty straightforward. I created a class called AwaitStatusReportThreadClass to use the pub/sub methods described [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/) to update the UI. The init method of this class has an infinite loop that checks for status messages. When one is found it updates the StatusBar message.

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import wx
import sys
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub


class AwaitStatusReportThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    """This class should pass messages to the UI class"""
    def __init__(self, messageQueue):
        """Init worker Thread Class"""
        self.messageQueue = messageQueue

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        """This code executes when the thread is run"""

        KeepRunningStatusThread = True
        while KeepRunningStatusThread:
            sys.stdout.flush()

            try:
                msg = self.messageQueue.get()
                self.messageQueue.task_done()
            except:
                pass

            if msg == "Shutdown":
                # Kill this thread
                KeepRunningStatusThread = False

            else:
                pub.sendMessage("UI", msg=msg)


class UI2(wx.Frame):
    """This class is the UI"""
    def __init__(self, taskQueue, messageQueue, stopQueue, parent=None):

        self.taskQueue = taskQueue
        self.messageQueue = messageQueue
        self.stopQueue = stopQueue

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="TestApp")

        #Main panel
        sizerMain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Add the status bar
        panelStatusBar = wx.Panel(self)
        sizerStatusBar = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        panelStatusBar.SetSizer(sizerStatusBar)

        self.StatusBar_Main = wx.StatusBar(panelStatusBar, wx.NewId())
        sizerStatusBar.Add(self.StatusBar_Main, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 2)

        #Add the status bar sizer to the main sizer
        sizerMain.Add(panelStatusBar, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        #Add the progress bar
        panelProgressBar = wx.Panel(self)
        sizerProgressBar = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        panelProgressBar.SetSizer(sizerProgressBar)
        self.Gauge_ProgressBar = wx.Gauge(panelProgressBar, wx.NewId())
        sizerProgressBar.Add(self.Gauge_ProgressBar, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizerMain.Add(panelProgressBar,0,wx.EXPAND)

        #Layout the frame
        self.SetSizer(sizerMain)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        sizerMain.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show(show=True)

        #Subscribe to messages from the messageQueue
        pub.subscribe(self.HandleStatusUpdate, "UI")
        AwaitStatusReportThreadClass(self.messageQueue)

    def HandleStatusUpdate(self, msg):
        """
        This def updates the UI from a pubsub subscription

        """
        StatusBar = self.StatusBar_Main
        StatusBar.PushStatusText(msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #Make multiprocessing work when app is frozen
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    taskQueue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue() #Specifies tasks to be completed by the GenInst process
    messageQueue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue() #Holds status messages / progress messages to update the message zone and progress bar in the UI
    stopQueue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue() #Allows cancel operation button to function

    messageQueue.put("Please wait while the GenInst background process starts...")

    #Start the UI
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = UI2(taskQueue=taskQueue, messageQueue=messageQueue, stopQueue=stopQueue)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was easy. I'll leave it here in case it helps anyone in the future.

All that was needed was to restructure the AwaitStatusReportThreadClass to use wx.CallAfter to post the message. I added a postMessage function to the class and called it using `wx.CallAfter(self.postMessage, msg)`

```
class AwaitStatusReportThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    """This class should pass messages to the UI class"""
    def __init__(self, messageQueue):
        """Init worker Thread Class"""
        self.messageQueue = messageQueue

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        """This code executes when the thread is run"""

        KeepRunningStatusThread = True
        while KeepRunningStatusThread:
            sys.stdout.flush()

            try:
                msg = self.messageQueue.get()
                self.messageQueue.task_done()
                wx.CallAfter(self.postMessage, msg)

            except:
                pub.sendMessage("Failed")         

    def postMessage(self, msg):
        pub.sendMessage("UI", msg=msg)
```